# Using addView on a View after calling removeView

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, view

I have a TextView that I want dynamically added and removed, depending on the text in a EditText. I currently have it correctly starting off removed using removeView, but when I try to call addView, it throws a NullPointerException, assumingly because the TextView is null once removed?

Here is how I have my code:

```
final TextView tagsText = (TextView)postDialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.newPostTagsText);
//remove since start with no tags
((LinearLayout)tagsText.getParent()).removeView(tagsText);

if(currentTags.equals("Tags: <font color='#33B5E5'></font>") && tagsText.isShown())
    ((LinearLayout)tagsText.getParent()).removeView(tagsText);
else if(!currentTags.equals("Tags: <font color='#33B5E5'></font>") && !tagsText.isShown())
    //this line below throws the NullPointerException
    ((LinearLayout)tagsText.getParent()).addView(tagsText);
```

When the very last line is called, which I can tell it is called at the correct time, the app crashes and throws a nullpointerexception. What is the correct way to readd the view?

Comment: What do you want to do in the first place? Just hide and show the `TextView`? If yes you can do that a lot simpler by setting the visibility of the `TextView` with `setVisiblity()`. Set the visibility to `View.GONE` if you want to hide it and `View.VISIBLE` if you want to show it again.

Comment: The reason I was avoiding that was because it leaves the dimensions of the view still there, where I was wanting to completely remove it.

Comment: If you set it to `View.GONE` it is as if the `TextView` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide the `View` you can do that much simpler by setting the visibility, there are three possible visibility values:

- `View.VISIBLE` - This means the `View` is visible.
- `View.INVISIBLE` - This means the `View` is invisible but still part of the layout.
- `View.GONE` - This means the `View` is invisible and doesn't influence the layout anymore.

In your case setting the `Views` visibility to either `View.VISIBLE` or `View.GONE` seems to be what you are looking for.

You can set the visibility like this:

```
textView.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE);
```

or

```
textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score -1):

You will want to create a new TextView, because you declared the first TextView final. If you add an extra line in the else if statement like this, it should work:

```
else if (!currentTags.equals("Tags: <font color='#33B5E5'></font>") && !tagsText.isShown()) {
    //this line below throws the NullPointerException
     final TextView tagsText1 = (TextView)postDialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.newPostTagsText);
    ((LinearLayout)tagsText.getParent()).addView(tagsText1);
}
```